# isinstance(list.append (BuiltinFunctionType, BuiltinMethodType)) == False

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.7, introspection

On non-builtin types, `types.FunctionType` and `types.MethodType` behave as expected:

```
>>> isinstance(MyClass.func, FunctionType)
True
>>> isinstance(MyClass.func, MethodType)
False
>>> isinstance(MyClass().func, FunctionType)
False
>>> isinstance(MyClass().func, MethodType)
True
```

However, on a built-in type, `BuiltinFunctionType` and `BuiltinMethodType` don't behave accordingly:

```
>>> isinstance(list.append, (FunctionType, MethodType,
...                          BuiltinFunctionType, BuiltinMethodType))
False  <- Why??
>>> isinstance([].append, (FunctionType, MethodType))
False
>>> isinstance([].append, BuiltinFunctionType)
True  <- Why??
>>> isinstance([].append, BuiltinMethodType)
True
```

Now this does't make sense, does it? Can someone explain?

EDIT: `isinstance(list.append, MethodDescriptorType) == True`. Can someone explain how `MethodDescriptorType` differs from `BuiltinMethodType` and why do we need it? The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodDescriptorType) doesn't really say much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BuiltinFunctionType` and `BuiltinMethodType` are just different names referring to the same object:

```
>>> BuiltinFunctionType is BuiltinMethodType
True
```

`isinstance(list.append, BuiltinMethodType)` is false because it's not a method (i.e. an instance method bound to some object). The method binding happens through `object.__getattribute__`, so the functions defined with a class are just plain functions:

```
>>> def func(x): pass
... 
>>> class MyClass: func = func
... 
>>> MyClass.func is func
True
```

and hence `isinstance(MyClass.func, FunctionType)`. This works because all functions are [non-data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol):

```
>>> func.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x7f80abe57400>
```

For builtin types these objects (e.g. `list.append`) are also dedicated descriptors that handle the binding to their objects. So `x = []; x.append` returns a bound method which was created by the descriptor `list.append` and bound to the object `x`:

```
>>> type(list.append)
<class 'method_descriptor'>
```

Comment: "_binding happens through `object.__getattribute__`_" ‒ can you elaborate what do you mean by that?

Comment: @kyrill When you do `x.y` then effectively `type(x).__getattribute__(x, 'y')` is called which performs the name resolution of `y` in the context of `x` (data descriptors, instance variables, non-data descriptors (methods), class variables through the MRO (method resolution order)). If it finds `y` to be a method, it will call its `__get__` to create and return a `MethodType` object (see the [Descriptors HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)). I'll update my answer to better reflect that.

Comment: Good to know about `__get__` and the fact that it can be called on any function and with any argument. This could be misused for a quick-and-dirty partial application for when one is too lazy for `from functools import partial`.